# Checking if a date picker value is less than todays date MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am building application in MVC4 and I am trying to make sure that when a user inputs a date from the date picker and the form is submitted, that the date entered is not less than today's date.

Here is my Model:

```
 public class Job
{

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Target Date for Site Survey")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? TargetDateSurvey { get; set; }

}
```

My Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Job job)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            job.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            job.JobstatusID = 1;
            db.Jobs.Add(job);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.ClientID = new SelectList(db.Clients, "ClientID", "ClientName", job.ClientID);
        ViewBag.JobstatusID = new SelectList(db.JobStatusLookUps, "JobstatusID", "JobStatusDescription", job.JobstatusID);
        ViewBag.JobID = new SelectList(db.AssignAssessors, "JobID", "JobID", job.JobID);
        return View(job);
    }
```

And View:

```
@model fieldManagementSystem.Models.Job

                <div class="editor">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TargetDateSurvey)
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TargetDateSurvey)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TargetDateSurvey)
                </div>
```

Where about's would I validate this in the Model or Controller? And what is the best method to doing this?

Any guidance would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly simple to validate it in the controller.  You add a custom invalid state, and then the ModelState will act accordingly.

```
public ActionResult Create(Job job)
{
    if (job.TargetDateSurvey.Value < DateTime.Today)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("TargetDateSurvey", "Date must be today or later.");
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    ...
}
```